# How do I open a new window in the same monitor?

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, monitor, window

I have 2 monitors and using Oneiric Ocelot Ubuntu. If I have opened firefox on my first monitor and want open new window, new window is always opened on the  second monitor. How I can set using 1 monitor in the application? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual monitor applications opening on wrong monitor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9921/dual-monitor-applications-opening-on-wrong-monitor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start firefox with

```
firefox --display=:0.0
```

Where 0.0 corresponds to the display you want to open. Probably you have the first display as 0.0 and the second as 0.1. If you have nVidia then you can open the NVIDIA X Server Settings panel to see which number corresponds to which monitor.

Comment: Yes, that works but I think that we should tell Canonical that better solution for WM is open new window of the same process is open it on the same monitor where primary process of application running. How we should that?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems many windows (normals and dialog windows) open in the other monitor, but I solved this with the plugin "place window" from the CompizConfig.

In the general tab, I used this configuration:

Workarounds (check)
Positioning mode: centered
Multi Output Mode: Use Output Device with Pointe

**And the most important**

Forcing the window positioning : (type=Dialog) | type=Normal

Now all windows appear in the center of the monitor active or where the pointer is located.