# Some applications always open on the secondary screen?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual monitor applications opening on wrong monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9921/dual-monitor-applications-opening-on-wrong-monitor)

I have a dual screen setup. Some applications always open on my secondary screen.
How can I fix this behavior?

In Unity 3D there's a setting in CompizConfig to open windows centered on current desktop.
I'm using Oneiric 64-bit.