# Twinview dialog boxes all open in secondary screen

Tags: 11.10, twinview, dialog

I'm using Twinview with Oneiric 64bit with a nVidia card.
I have my primary monitor (with DVI) positioned to absolute 0 and my secondary to the right (with HDMI).

**My applications open on the primary monitor but all dialog boxes like the following opens on the secondary**

- shutdown
- *reload confirmation* on firefox
- *Save changes to document* on gedit
- admin passwords

So when my secondary screen is not on, I am forced to each time <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> in order to move the new box on the primary display

That's also doing it with some application windows but I got it corrected with *CCSM Window Placement*

---

This question seems to be already asked but my problem concerns dialog boxes.

[Dual monitor applications opening on wrong monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9921/dual-monitor-applications-opening-on-wrong-monitor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same problem here.  The fix:

1. Install ccsm as explained in earlier post.
2. Go to General->General Options->Display Settings.
3. From drop down menu of 'Overlapping Output Handling' select 'Prefer smaller output'.
   (My monitor is smaller than my TV.)
   Apparently the 'Smart Mode' isn't very smart (at least on my setup).

Comment: I used to be wary of things using the term "smart". Thank you, it seems to work

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Compiz I find that using the Place Windows plugin is a good way to have predictable windows placement.

You'll need to install the CompizConfig Settings Manager (aka ccsm) to get going. One warning: CCSM can break things if you run around doing things you're not supposed to, so focus on the task at hand :)

I currently have mine set to:

- Placement Mode: Centred
- Multi Output Mode: Use output device with pointer

Comment: Thank you, I used these settings and it fixed the problem for application windows but not for the dialog boxes

Answer (score 2):

In ccsm under (Place Windows) you should see (Force placement windows) you can type this "type=dialog" without quotes.