# Ubuntu 22.04 - How to open app on monitor where they are clicked at

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 22.04

I have a setup with 4 monitors. My 3rd monitor is my main monitor.

I got the dock on each monitor and the dock only shows the open apps on that monitor(`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors true`).

What I want, is that when I click on chrome on monitor 1, it opens on monitor 1 and if I open it on monitor 2, to open on monitor 2, etc.

First, when I opened chrome on monitor 2, it opened on monitor 1(not main). I found a "solution" to this behavior, which was kinda sketchy but at least made chrome open on my main(3rd) monitor: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328157/815263

It's still not what I want, but finding solutions to this problem is kinda hard, as most resources I find are for older ubuntu versions and do not apply to 22.04, or simply advice to install tools that don't apply to gnome.

Does anyone know how to configure ubuntu 22.04 with gnome to open apps in the display they were clicked without configuring each and every app manually?